# External table refresh in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a external table which is based on s3 integartion.

The files in s3 bucket is refreshed only once a day at 12:30 UTC.

Option 1:

I do auto refresh of table.

```
create or replace external table EXT_TABLE
(
  "ID" VARCHAR as (nullif(value:c1,'')::VARCHAR),
  ...........
)
with location = @STAGE_NAME
auto_refresh = true
file_format = user_data_format
pattern = '.*su.*[.]csv';
```

Option 2:
Create a task that runs at 13 UTC and does

```
 alter external table EXT_TABLE refresh;
```

Do we have any difference in cost between 2 options refreshing using task or option 1 refreshing automatically knowing the files in s3 would be overwritten only once a day.

What is the better approach and what is the difference in cost in option 1 and 2?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the S3 bucket will be refreshed only once a day at 12:30 UTC, I would go with the task.

First of all, there is a small charge for receiving notifications:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-external-intro.html#billing-for-refreshing-external-table-metadata

I am not sure about this, but you may receive multiple notifications if you upload multiple files to your S3 bucket. (*Hope someone verifies this*)